# Find version of js library in compiled js files

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a `dist` folder that contains the outcome of `npm install`.

Assuming I do not have access to the `package.json` used when compiling the distributable, how can I find the version of a specific library that was used during the installation?

Comment: You can often find in the compiled files some comments about the libraries used with creator's name and version. Maybe you can check if you find the information here ?

Answer (score 0):

use `npm -v` command

example:
`npm -v <package_name>`

Comment: Are you sure this work if OP doesn't have the `package.json` file ? Also, I don't think it is the right command.

Comment: what is more, my dist is in a container that does not have `node`/`npm` installed

Comment: @pkaramol I think it's not possible to detect the packages version from output file. The bundler system just takes the main entry of package and bundles it to main output file. From this perspective package files are the same as your custom files.